# Why is Visual Studio 2019 looking for files in the DEBUG folder during a build when Configuration is set to RELEASE?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build a project, having set Configuration to "Release":

```
Active solution configuration:
Release                      Any CPU

Project contexts (check the project configurations to build or deploy)
MyProj1  ....... Release ... Any CPU    Build checked
MyLibr1..........Release ... Any CPU    Build checked
```

But Visual Studio is looking in the **debug** folder:

> Could not find file bin\Debug\some.dll   ...         Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets | Line 3858

In References, the path to the DLL in question  points to a folder location beneath Program Files (x86).

P.S. And when I change the configuration to "Debug", Visual Studio is looking for files in `bin\Release`.